# jmeter HTTP Request Retrieve All Embedded Resources incl subdomain

Tags: regex, jmeter, web-testing

I'm new to jmeter but I'm trying to set the "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" in the default "HTTP Request" module to include a subdomain which handles my media files

What I have tried is

```
http://(sub\.)?example\.com/.*
```

But it's only includes files from the primary domain example.com and not from sub.example.com. Any one who can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default JMeter will **include** all the embedded resources no matter of origin. You may want to [exclude external domains](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1903905-excluding-domains-from-the-load-test), but given you leave "URLs must match" blank - JMeter will capture all the images, scripts, styles, whatever.

Comment: Thx Dmitri T  Ill follow your suggestion, unfortunately I do not have enough post to give you +1 for your answer :/